# Qt client and php server connection

Tags: mysql, qt, ftp, wamp

I have coded my application in Qt 4 and I need to connect it to a wamp server to send a file and a MySQL query. How can I do it in Qt as I can't use php coding in mobile side?

Answer (score 0):

[QNetworkRequest](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QNetworkRequest.html) can access your wamp server.